# scala, play framework pattern type is incompatible with expected type

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I have an issue with play framework and scala. My 2 Model class are below:

In here UserProfile have one Foriegn key to User Account and MyFriend hav 2 Foriegn key 1. user_Id from user profile and friend_ID from Userprofile

```
case class UserProfile(id: Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, useraccountid: Option[Long], name:
String, date_of_birth: Date, gender: String, image: String,status:String)
object UserProfile{
  val simple = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("user_profile.id") ~
      get[Option[Long]]("user_profile.user_account_id") ~
      get[String]("user_profile.name") ~
      get[Date]("user_profile.date_of_birth") ~
      get[String]("user_profile.gender") ~
      get[String]("user_profile.image") ~
      get[String]("user_profile.status") map {
        case id ~ user_account_id ~ name ~ date_of_birth ~ gender ~ image ~ status =>
          UserProfile(id, user_account_id, name, date_of_birth, gender, image,status )
      }
  }
     /**
       * Parse a userProfile from a MyFriend
       */
      val withMyFriend =UserProfile.simple ~ (MyFriend.simple ?) map{
        case userprofile  ~ myfriend  => (userprofile, myfriend)
      }
      /**
       * Register a new useraccount.
       *
       * @param useraccount.
       */
      def insert(userProfile: UserProfile): Long = {
        DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
          SQL(
            """
              insert into USER_PROFILE(USER_ACCOUNT_ID ,NAME,DATE_OF_BIRTH,GENDER,IMAGE,STATUS) values (
                {user_account_id}, {name},{date_of_birth},{gender},{image},{status}
              )
            """).on(
              'user_account_id -> userProfile.useraccountid.get,
              'name -> userProfile.name,
              'date_of_birth -> userProfile.date_of_birth,
              'gender -> userProfile.gender,
              'image -> userProfile.image,
              'status -> userProfile.status).executeUpdate()
        }
      }
    }
```

and

```
case class Post(id: Pk[Long]= NotAssigned, name:String, image:String, time:Date)

    object Post{

      /**
       * Parse a Post from a Resultset
       */
      val simple ={
        get[Pk[Long]]("post.id") ~
        get[String]("post.name")~
        get[String]("post.image")~
        get[Date]("post.time") map {
          case id ~ name ~ image ~ time=> Post(id,name,image,time)
        }
      }
      /**
       * Parse a Post from a UserPost
       */
      val withUserPost = Post.simple ~ (UserPost.simple ?) map{
        case post ~ userpost => (post, userpost)
      }

       /**
       * Register a new post.
       *
       * @param post 
       */
      def insert(post: Post): Long = {
        DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
          SQL(
            """
              insert into POST(NAME,IMAGE,TIME) values (
                {name}, {image}, {time}
              )
            """).on(
              'name -> post.name,
              'image -> post.image,
              'time -> post.time).executeUpdate()
        }
      }


 /**
   * Authonticate
   */
  def authenticate(post: Post) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      val postFound = SQL(
        """
          select * from POST 
          where ID = (id}
        """).on(
          'Id -> post.id
          ).as(Post.simple.singleOpt)
      postFound
    }
  }
}/** * Find Post With UserPost */ def userPost(post_id: Long) = { DB.withConnection { implicit connection => val userPost = SQL( """ select * from USER_POST where USER_POST_ID = {user_post_id} """).on( 'post_id -> post_id).as(UserPost.simple.singleOpt) userPost } }
```

and here is my controller application:

```
     /* Authenticate User For CreatePost*/

  def authendticatePost = Action { implicit request =>
    val alert: Alert = new Alert("", "")
    Common.setAlert(alert)
    createPostForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.createPost(errors, "There is some error")),
      post => {
        val postOpt = Post.authenticate(post)
        postOpt match {
          case None =>

            val alert: Alert = new Alert("error", "Invalid Credentials")
            Common.setAlert(alert)
            val invalidCredentialsForm = Application.createPostForm.fill(Post(NotAssigned, post.name,post.image,post.time))
            Ok(views.html.createPost(invalidCredentialsForm, "Invalid Credentials"))
          case Some(authpost: Post) =>
            val userSession = request.session + ("Id" -> authpost.id.toString)
            val createPostOpt = Post.userPost(authpost.id.get)
            createPostOpt match {
              case None => Ok(views.html.createPost(Application.createPostForm, "")).withSession(userSession)
              case Some(postFound: Post) =>
                val createPostFormWithDetails = Application.createPostForm.fill(postFound)
                Ok(views.html.createPost(createPostFormWithDetails, "")).withSession(userSession)
            }

        }
      })

  }


  /**
    Create Post*/
  def createPost = Action { implicit request =>


    val alert: Alert = new Alert("", "")
    Common.setAlert(alert)
    createPostForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest(views.html.createPost(errors, "There is some error")),
      post => {
        Post.findByPostName(post.name).isEmpty match {
          case true =>
            val createpost = Post(NotAssigned, post.name, post.image, post.time)
            Post.insert(createpost)
            Common.setAlert(alert)
          case false =>
            val createpost = Post(NotAssigned, post.name, post.image, post.time)
            Post.insert(createpost)
            Common.setAlert(alert)
        }
        Results.Redirect("/post")

      })
  }
/** Redirect To  post**/

  def post = Action { implicit request =>
     Ok(views.html.createPost(Application.createPostForm, "post"))
  }
```

and here is my routes:

```
POST /createPost        controllers.Application.createPost
GET  /post              controllers.Application.post
```

and I've got this error at compile time:

```
 pattern type is incompatible with expected type; found : object None required: Unit 
    : pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
     found   : object None
      required: Unit
    Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
                 case None =>
                      ^
```

Comment: On which line does the error happen? I don't see the methods `Post.userPost` or `Post.authenticate` in your snippets, but are you sure that they don't return `Unit` by mistake?

Comment: /**
   * Find Post With UserPost   */

  def userPost(post_id: Long) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      val userPost = SQL(
        """
          select * from USER_POST
          where USER_POST_ID = {user_post_id}
        """).on(
          'post_id -> post_id).as(UserPost.simple.singleOpt)
      userPost
    }
  }

Comment: this one looks fine, but can you edit your question to add the two missing methods? It would be more readable.

Comment: ok sir i just updated..

Comment: What about `Post.authenticate`? That one is still missing.

Comment: again soory i just updated